# Banana cultivar identification

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found a cultivar of banana that I haven't seen before (and that was significantly different from the standard Cavendish cultivar) in a market in Hong Kong today, due to the language barrier (Mandarin Chinese vs Cantonese), I was unable to ask the store owner about the name of the banana.

This is a picture of the banana, pictured next to a pack of standard AA batteries, as well as the peeled banana and a transverse section of the banana.

Can anyone identify the specific cultivar of this banana?

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same cultivar of banana being sold in a market while on a recent trip to Sulawesi, Indonesia. I was told by the owner that this cultivar is locally known as the [pisang kepok](http://www.straitstimes.com/world/africa/local-bananas-a-cheat-sheet-on-the-common-banana-types-sold-here), or alternatively the [Saba banana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saba_banana). This cultivar is thought to originate from the Philippines.

[image]

[image]